# Logitech K750 Mac version keyboard - the keypad stopped working

Tags: 10.10, keyboard, logitech

Last week after upgrades my keyboard stopped, but still works fine in Windows.

The 5 key though will bring up a context edit menu.

Anyone else have this since the last two sets of upgrades?  Any solution or ideas?

Comment: Do you have any active PPA that might affect normal updates? (ie Ubuntu-X team or xorg edgers, etc)

Comment: No... and it was working fine until a couple of days ago.  I attributed it, perhaps wrongly, to the latest updates.  I am running 10.10.